# Draw ticks over external plot using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I plotted a contour/surface plot with `gnuplot` using `set pm3d map` and want to include this picture via `\addplot graphics {...};`.

When I match the plot area of the `axis` environment with the plot range of the gnuplot picture, the ticks from pgfplots are "behind" the plot and thus not visible anymore.

Is there a possibility, to draw the coordinate system in the foreground, or do I have to turn the ticks to the outside of the plot?

---

The relevant part of the code should be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\w {0.4*\textwidth};
  \begin{axis}[
      scale only axis,
      width = \w,
      height = \w,
      xmin = 0.4,
      xmax = 0.9,
      ymin = -22.5,
      ymax = 202.5,
      scaled ticks = false,
      xtick = {0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9},
      xticklabels = {0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9},
      xlabel = $\omega/\omega_p$,
      ytick = {0,45,...,180},
      yticklabels = {$0$,$\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{4}$,$\pi$},
      ylabel = angle $\varphi$ around center of sphere
      ]
    \addplot graphics[
        xmin = 0.4,
        xmax = 0.9,
        ymin = -45,
        ymax = 225,
        xtick = {0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9},
        ] {data/half.png};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Would you convert your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PGFPlots have both a layering system and a drawing order system. The option `axis on top` draws the axis lines and ticks over the graph area.